# List all posts in a particular page

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I have a small wordpress blog. There are around 50 posts in the blog. I want to create a page which will enlist all the post titles. I have used "W4 Post List" wordpress plugin but that doesn't solve my issue. Please suggest me any alternative wordpress plugin or code.

Comment: "W4 Post List" looks like interesting. what doesn't fit with it ?

Comment: Please suggest me some alternative

Comment: if you want help, a good start is to answer the questions http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create a custom page template and paste the code

```
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

for custom page template visit [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) and for WP_Query visit [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked.